# Having trouble recreating this login page in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a login page based on [this](https://davidsongifted.blackboard.com/) one in HTML and CSS. Of course, my logo will be different, and I am trying to add some transparency to the background image.

I'm new to web dev, but I don't think this is too complicated. It's just one background pic, with a single div spreading across the screen to hold the username and password bars.

I have put what I've got so far into this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6eLuw2th/

Here's the code:

```css
body {
 opacity: 0.2;
 background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/d/e/104382.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 z-index: -1;
}

form {
 border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
 z-index: 0;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #8C1515;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 0;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the username/password content appears to be behind the image (even though the z-index is -1 for the background?). I do want to make the background appear slightly transparent, but have been having a bit of trouble that as well. Furthermore, my username and password bars stretch across the entire screen; I would prefer for them to be more like the example page I'm trying to recreate, with the login info bars restricted to the middle of the screen.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue you are facing is not about `z-index`. the issue is that you have `opacity:0.2` set on the body, that's why it looks weird:

```
body {
    opacity: 0.2; /* just remove this line */
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/d/e/104382.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

also I amended the form to have less width and centered:

```
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 0;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Here is a working snippet:

```css
body {
 background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/d/e/104382.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 z-index: -1;
}

form {
 border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
 z-index: 0;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  color: #FFF;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #8C1515;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 0;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Body opacity affects everything in the body, so don't do it there.
Instead put the background image in a div

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

Then the css for it

```
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/d/e/104382.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

For the input fields make sure not to have the width as 100%

If you want to have columns then check out:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp

Answer (score 1):

1) You are not loading a faded background. You're loading a solid background and trying to fade the body, which faded EVERYTHING within the body, including your form.

2) Remove "width=100%" from your INPUT parts in the CSS and it will not stretch across the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/*
  Make the background in a div
*/
.bg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/d/e/104382.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

form {
 border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

button {
  background-color: #8C1515;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;

}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;

}

.container {
  padding: 16px;

}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;

}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- the div that contains the background -->
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code snippets for the effect you want to achieve.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/d/e/104382.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

form {
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #8C1515;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 180px;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.3);
  ;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}


/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required><br>
      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
      <button type="submit">Login</button><br>
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```